# PHP use Variable Scope

Tags: php, variables, global-variables, slim

I am using the slimphp framework and am confused about the variable scope of my routing functions. I have the following:

```
$app = new \Slim\Slim(array(
 'templates.path' => '../templates/',
 'view' => new Slim\Extras\Views\Twig()
));

$user = SES\Session::getInstance();

include 'routes.php';

$app->run();
```

//`Routes.php`

```
$app->get("/", function() use ($app, $user){
....
}
```

`Routes.php` fails if i do not add `global $user;` to the top:

`Notice: Undefined variable: user`

Why is it that I can access the `$app` var from this file but I cannot access the `$user` var?

Comment: What line does notice referres to? What if you move the `routes.php` contents in place of `include`?

Comment: what othercode surrounds that $app->get() call? if it's inside a function or method, then of course it's not going to have a $user defined locally.

Comment: If I move the contents of routes into the main bootstrap it does not give me that error. There is nothing encapsulating the `$app->get()`. I guess it makes sense that since it is in an external file I need to call `global $user` but not sure why I wouldn't need to call `global $app`

Comment: @Shawn Northrop: it's not possible. What is the whole contents of `Routes.php`?

Comment: @zerkms: My routes files are growing but its all the same idea. `<?php $app->('....', function() use($app,$user){..code..}); ... more routes ... ?>` Nothing more than that.

Comment: @Shawn Northrop: it's not possible. Create 2 files: a.php: `<?php $var="i'm here"; include 'b.php'; ?>` and b.php: `<?php echo $var; ?>` and see it works

Comment: I have narrowed down the problem. I don't actually call `include 'routes.php';` I have a utility function that loads all routes in a folder. I call this in my bootstrap: `SES\Util::loadRoutes('../routes');` This is a static function that reads a dir and does a `require $filename;` for every file. I must have dealt with this in the past because inside this function I declare `global $app;` Sooo.. I still don't fully understand when I need to call `global` but this solves part of the confusion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have narrowed down the problem. I don't actually call include 'routes.php'; I have a utility function that loads all routes in a folder. I call this in my bootstrap: SES\Util::loadRoutes('../routes'); This is a static function that reads a dir and does a require $filename; for every file. I must have dealt with this in the past because inside this function I declare global $app; Sooo.. I still don't fully understand when I need to call global but this solves part of the confusion!